# How to send using with attachment and html body using mailx

Tags: html, linux, shell, content-type, mailx

I want to send an e-mail using mailx which has an attachment and HTML code on the body.
Setting the Content-type to "text/html" mail comes with file binary content on the body instead of attached.

```
echo "" >> $MAILFILE
echo "<HTML>" >> $MAILFILE
echo "<HEAD>" >> $MAILFILE
echo "</HEAD>" >> $MAILFILE
echo "<BODY>" >> $MAILFILE
echo "<table border="1">" >>$MAILFILE
echo "<tr bgcolor=#C0C0C0>" >>$MAILFILE
echo "<td><b>OUTAGE</b></td>" >>$MAILFILE
echo "<td>$OUTAGE_COUNT</td>" >>$MAILFILE
echo "</tr> </table><br>" >>$MAILFILE
echo "</table>" >> $MAILFILE
echo "</BODY></HTML>" >> $MAILFILE

(uuencode outage.zip outage.zip;cat $MAILFILE) | mailx -s "Outage Payments Status
Content-type: text/html" $distro -- -f ${EMAIL_FROM}
```

Result - Body's email:

`````````
begin 644 outage.zip M4$L#!!0````(`,:$(T5RYN"0#P```.D#```3`!4`;W5T86=E7W!A>6UE;G1S M+F-S=E54"0`#)&X'5"1N!U15>`0`.GX1@5-0@`(3A5$P"D;!,`5<&%Y;65N=',N8W-V550%``,D;@=457@``%!+!08``````0`!`$X```!5 %```````` ` end
`````````

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead use sendmail as follows :

#!/usr/bin/ksh

export MAILTO="spam@ebay.com"
export SUBJECT="Mail Subject"
export BODY="/tmp/email_body.html"
export ATTACH="/tmp/attachment.txt"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
 echo 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-q1w2e3r4t5"'
 echo
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
 cat $BODY
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5'
 echo 'Content-Type: application; name="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
 echo 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'$(basename $ATTACH)'"'
 uuencode -m $ATTACH $(basename $ATTACH)
 echo '---q1w2e3r4t5--'
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail $MAILTO
```